# Are my calculations of Pythagorean Triplets including 0 correct?

Tags: pythagorean-triples

So I was playing around with Pythagorean Triplets and I decided to see what happens when certain sides are equal to 0.

For a² + b² = c²,
If a = 0,
Since (2m)² + (m² - 1)² = (m² + 1)²,
m = 0
Therefore, 0, -1, 1

Repeating the same process for b and c yields 2, 0, 2 and 2i, -2, 0, respectively. Is there someone who can check my process? Also I would love it if there was some way to use this to construct a triangle.

Comment: If $a^2+b^2=c^2$ and $a=0$, then immediately $b^2=c^2$; the solutions of this are $b=\pm c$ for any $c$ in the world.

Comment: A triangle is defined as having three sides. If one of the sides is $0$, it in essence does not exist, and the figure to be constructed is a line segment in which the two "sides" remaining are superimposed.